# Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a purely real number field. What is the Pontryagin Dual of $\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis

I know that the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is the group of profinite integers: $$\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$$ under the addition operation, where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of prime numbers ($2,3,5,7,\ldots$) and the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$s are the rings of $p$-adic integers.

Now, let $\mathbb{F}$ be a purely real number field (ideally, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}$, the intersection of the field of algebraic numbers with $\mathbb{R}$). Then, what is the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Z}$?

My guess is that it would be:$$\widehat{\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Z}}\cong\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}}}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$$ where $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}}$ is the set of places/primes of $\mathbb{F}$, and $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers (i.e., the closure of $\mathbb{Z}\left[p\right]$ with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value). Is this correct? If not, what is $\widehat{\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Z}}$?

Finally, insofar as Fourier analysis is concerned, am I correct in assuming that characters, fractional parts, Fourier transforms, haar measures and the like all work out to be formally equivalent to what one does when $p\in\mathbb{P}$? That is to say, assuming that I know how to do Fourier analysis on $\widehat{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}\cong\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, is there anything special I need to know about Fourier analysis on $\widehat{\mathbb{F}/\mathbb{Z}}$? Or do all the formulae generally work in the same way?

Comment: I'm not very conversant with this, but isn't Pontryagin dual only about the additive structure. That is, for this purpose $\Bbb{F}/\Bbb{Z}\cong \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}\oplus \Bbb{Q}^{n-1}$, $n=[\Bbb{F}:\Bbb{Q}]$?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be modding out the ring of integers of $\mathbb{F}$, not just $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: No, I do not. I am doing fourier analysis on the hilbert space $L^{2}\left(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\right)$ of functions $f:\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which are "integrable" with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. I realized I might be able to extend my methods to $L^{2}\left(\left(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap\mathbb{R}\right)/\mathbb{Z}\right)$, but I don't know how to formulate and compute the fourier transform (and inverse transform) on that space.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "square-integrable". Anyhow, the point is, my functions are only known to be of period $1$; that is, invariant with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$-translations. Invariance with respect to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{F}}$-translations doesn't follow from that—not to my knowledge, anyhow. :)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Algebra is not my strong suit; I'm looking for confirmation from someone who knows better. Moreover, if your answer is correct, then, my interest in the maximal purely real number field makes your proposed answer especially troubling, and I don't quite know how to work with it, so extra explanation would be much appreciated.